# how do you group subforms

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-sub-form

i have 4 subforms in a form i would like to group 2 of them together, and then apply some decorators to them.

here is what i have so far. w/in each subform i already have some display groups present

```
$this->setSubForms(array(
    'sub1'  => $sub1,
    'sub2'  => $sub2,
    'sub3'  => $sub3,
    'sub4'  => $sub4
));
```

i thought i could do something like

```
$set1 = $this->setSubFormDecorators(array(
    'sub1'  => $sub1,
    'sub2'  => $sub2
    ));
    $set1->setDecorator(array('something here'));

$set2 = $this->setSubFormDecorators(array(
    'sub3'  => $sub3,
    'sub4'  => $sub4
    ));
    $set2->setDecorator(array('something here'));
```

obviously this doesn't work at all.

I really couldn't find anything in ZF's documentation. I thought i post it here if anyone else has run across this quandary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

so basically i've figured it out.

first off you create "empty" subforms

```
$left = new Zend_Form_SubForm();
```

then you add the subforms you want inside of this "subform"

```
$left->setSubForms(array(
   'sub1'  => $sub1,
   'sub2'  => $sub2
));
```

you do the same thing for the other subform you want to add decorators to.

```
$right = new Zend_Form_SubForm();     

$right->setSubForms(array(
   'sub3'  => $sub3,
   'sub4'  => $sub4
));
```

then to your original form you add these new "$left" and "$right" subforms

```
$this->setSubForms(array(
   'left'  => $left,
   'right' => $right
));
```

you can then apply decorators to the "$left" and "$right" subforms as you see fit.

since i want to drop the fieldsets that encapsulate the elements inside
mine looks like this, you do the same to the other one.

```
    $left->setDecorators(array(
        'FormElements',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div')),
        ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `addDisplayGroup` will be fine in this case too?

Comment: no addDisplayGroup requires elements. I've figured it out. thanks though